# Visual Studio 2010 and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, utf-8

Is there a way that I can save my Visual Studio 2010 files as UTF-8 encoded?  I'm using VS.NET 2010 as a PHP editor using VS.PHP.

If there is a macro that will launch during the saving process that will handle this, that would be fine too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I went ahead and started using Notepad++ as that gave me everything I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File → Advanced Save Options. At least in Beta 2.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2010 Final:

File → Save as → In the "Save File as" dialog window click the small arrow in the "Save" button and select "Save with Encoding..."